# Create Record LWC Lightning-Record-Edit-Form Stage to Forecast-Category fields not dynamically changing

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-recordeditform, field-dependencies

I have an existing action on a contact that creates a new Opportunity.  The Stage field has picklist value mappings to the Forecast Category fields. On a Create-Record type of action, when the Stage picklist is changed, the Forecast-Category picklist changes automatically.

I am now replacing this with an LWC component in a Flow, and I am not seeing the same behavior between the Stage and Forecast Category fields.  When the Stage is changed, the Forecast Category does nothing.  Here is the stripped down LWC component.

```
 <template>
  <lightning-record-edit-form
    object-api-name={objectApiName}
    record-type-id={recordTypeId}
    onsubmit={handleSubmit}
  >
    <lightning-messages></lightning-messages>
    <lightning-input-field
      value={accountId}
      field-name={accountField}
      required
      onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field
      field-name={stageField}
      required
      onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-input-field>
    <lightning-input-field
      field-name={forecastCategoryNameField}
      required
      onchange={handleChange}
    ></lightning-input-field>
  </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

Nothing too special, Other field dependencies are automatically changing when a dependent picklist changes, just not the Stage and Forecast Category (which is mapped under the Stage field, not field dependencies).

Am I missing something in the Lightning-record-edit-form to make this automatic picklist cascade happen with LWC?